# Can I close all loaded XML files on disk without forcing garbage collection?

Tags: garbage-collection, xmldocument, xmlreader

I have coded a UI import tool that will scan a bunch of folders, locate all XML files in them, load them to do a first basic check on validity, then try to import them in the DB (which causes another even bigger bunch of validity checks to run).
When the basic checks or the import fails, the app shows a detailed error message to the user, so the user can open up the respective XML file and edit it.
BUT... the user CANNOT save the file, because the file "is in use by another process".

At that stage, all my importer objects are long gone, but I figured they might not be garbage collected yet, so they keep open handles to the XML files. So I tried a GC.Collect() after the checking/import process and then magically the user can edit and save the XML files.

All my code ever does with the XML files is this:

```
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(m_xmlInputFile);
m_XmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
m_XmlDocument.Load(reader);
```

'reader' is a local variable, so it goes out of scope immediately, m_XmlDocument is a member variable that will live as long as the importer object is alive. The importer object is a local variable in another function, so everything should end up in death row after all is said and done. Still it looks like waiting on death row might take a while...

Not that it matters much in my case, but just out of curiosity I would like to know if there is something I could do (apart from forcing a GC) to "free" the XML files on disk, so that the user can do his/her editing without surprises.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[`XmlReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx) implements `IDisposable`, and you're not holding up your end of the contract.

Either call `Dispose` on it at an appropriate time, or (better) surround the code that uses it in a `using` block:

```
using(XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(m_xmlInputFile))
{
    m_XmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
    m_XmlDocument.Load(reader);
}
```

If you *ever* find yourself forcing a garbage collection, you're doing something wrong (to within 99.99% certainty).

Nothing magical happens when a reference goes out of scope - yes, the object it refers to will become *eligible* for garbage collection (if that was the last remaining reference to the object), but no extra code will run.

Whereas, if the object holds resources, and ought to be cleaned up as soon as possible, it will implement the [disposable pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! I know that forcing a GC is a bad bad sign, so that's why I asked the question in the first place. I made a quick check for IDisposable before posting, but only checked XmlDocument not XmlReader :-)